# phpMyAdmin returns blank page

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am installing phpmyadmin 4.2.11 with php 5.3.3.

I have extracted to web server doc root.

When I browse it I get blank page.

I have followed steps in this page (http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install)

and I have tried solution 1.1 from this page (https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html) but did not success.

What would be the problem?

Comment: First you have to find out what the error is. Find your error log, or set errors to display. Then add those errors, if they don't help you solve the issue, to your question (edit your question, don't put it in a comment ;)  ). For check the numerous questions about how to set errors around here, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: By the way, version 4.2.11 is outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the mbstring support that has not installed yet.

Thanks to Nanne for pointing out to look after error log.

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved by modifying line 864 in phpmyadmin/export.php, change :

```
break 2;
```

By:

```
break;
```

Solution reference in this page https://superuser.com/questions/1111521/export-page-of-phpmyadmin-goes-blank-after-update-php5-to-php7-0

and actually the first reference is by bbalent answer https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11912
"Don't worry, this is a code mistake from the phpMyAdmin team: you are into one loop and not two nested loops. That's why you can't "break 2" (because 2 denotes that you're inside a nested loop). The error appears because PHP7 is stricter than former versions. By the way, this can fix other packages (PHPExcel, newer versions of phpMyAdmin etc.). Most of the time, the developper deleted the nested loop and forgot to update this line of code."